# Get value from another table with more than one join condition

Tags: postgresql

I want to find value from table two. On the table two it has more than one join condition. It always get every condition from table two. So the table one have duplicate record that i not want to be

**t1**

| id | trx_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | trx1234 |
| 2 | trx5678 |
| 3 | trx4321 |
| 4 | trx8765 |

**t2**

| id | trx_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | trx1234 | success |
| 2 | trx1234 | success |
| 3 | trx1234 | NULL |
| 4 | trx5678 | failed |
| 5 | trx4321 | NULL |

when i want to find status `success`, the result

| id | trx_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | trx1234 | success |

**Query**

```
SELECT a.*, b.trx_id, b.status
FROM
    t1 a
LEFT JOIN
    t2 b on a.trx_id = b.trx_id
WHERE b.status = 'success';
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why did you use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you have t2 in your `WHERE`? Also- If I understand your problem correctly, perhaps you need to use `EXSITS` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said table one have duplicate record but there table two have it.
according to your table structure.

this is helpful for you

```
SELECT distinct a.id, a.trx_id, b.status
FROM
    dbo.t1 a
LEFT JOIN
   dbo.t2 b on a.trx_id = b.trx_id
WHERE b.status = 'success';
```

Result will show

```
id | trx_id | status

1  |trx1234 | success
```